# Loop answers when retriveing data in VB

Tags: json, excel, vba

```
Sub FIND_ISBN()

    Dim jsonBooks As Object, auth, authInfo As Object, k
    Dim jsonBook As Object, bookDetails As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet, isbn, rngIsbn As Range, cell As Range
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Books")
    
    Set rngIsbn = ws.Range("A1:A5")
    
    For Each cell In rngIsbn
        isbn = cell.Value
        If Len(isbn) > 5 Then
            Set jsonBooks = BookInfo(isbn)
        
            'Note: the aPI only returns `{}` if there's no match to
            '      the ISBN, not (eg) status=404
            If Not jsonBooks Is Nothing Then
                If jsonBooks.Count = 0 Then
                    Debug.Print "No results"
                Else
                    For Each k In jsonBooks
                        Debug.Print "-------" & k & "----------"
                        Set jsonBook = jsonBooks(k)
                        Set bookDetails = jsonBook("details")
                        Debug.Print "Title:", bookDetails("title")
                        Debug.Print "Pub. Date:", bookDetails("publish_date")
                        For Each auth In bookDetails("authors")
                            Debug.Print "Author:", auth("name")
                        Next auth
                    Next k
                  End If
            End If
        End If 'have something to look up
    Next cell

End Sub

Function BookInfo(isbn) As Object
    Dim url As String
    url = "https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:" & isbn & "&jscmd=details&format=json"
    Set BookInfo = responseObject(url)
End Function

Function responseObject(url As String) As Object
    Dim json As Object, http As Object
    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .Send
        'Debug.Print .Status, .responseText
      * ** If .Status = 200 Then
            'Set responseObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
           ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Books").Cells(1, 3) = .responseText
        Else***
            Debug.Print .responseText, .Status
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

I;m trying to finalise some code in VB.. i can see this code fetching the isbn details but it is only putting the retreived answers into cell 1,3 as per the code and i'm not sure how to make this move & loop to the next cell down....

I'm trying to get it to run thru ISBN numbers retreive the data (this bit works) and then get the line information in the correct cell...  any ideas or pointers would be gratefully received..

Comment: Why are you modifying the function _responseObject_? I suggest to use the json object (like shown with the _Debug.Print_) and write these properties into your worksheet ( e.g. use  [offest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) to your _cell_)

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of an index as you loop though the cells of `rngIsbn`, use that index to move the output location after each output.

I added a parameter to your two functions, `OffsetValue`, which is used with the function `Offset` to turn the static `Cells(1, 3)` into a variable location based on `OffsetValue`.

```vb
Sub FIND_ISBN()

    Dim jsonBooks As Object, auth, authInfo As Object, k
    Dim jsonBook As Object, bookDetails As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet, isbn, rngIsbn As Range, cell As Range
    
    Dim OffsetValue As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Books")
    
    Set rngIsbn = ws.Range("A1:A5")
    
    For Each cell In rngIsbn
        isbn = cell.Value
        If Len(isbn) > 5 Then
            Set jsonBooks = BookInfo(isbn, OffsetValue)
            OffsetValue = OffsetValue + 1
            
            'Note: the aPI only returns `{}` if there's no match to
            '      the ISBN, not (eg) status=404
            If Not jsonBooks Is Nothing Then
                If jsonBooks.Count = 0 Then
                    Debug.Print "No results"
                Else
                    For Each k In jsonBooks
                        Debug.Print "-------" & k & "----------"
                        Set jsonBook = jsonBooks(k)
                        Set bookDetails = jsonBook("details")
                        Debug.Print "Title:", bookDetails("title")
                        Debug.Print "Pub. Date:", bookDetails("publish_date")
                        For Each auth In bookDetails("authors")
                            Debug.Print "Author:", auth("name")
                        Next auth
                    Next k
                  End If
            End If
        End If 'have something to look up
    Next cell

End Sub

Function BookInfo(isbn, Optional OffsetValue As Long = 0) As Object
    Dim url As String
    url = "https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:" & isbn & "&jscmd=details&format=json"
    Set BookInfo = responseObject(url, OffsetValue)
End Function

Function responseObject(url As String, Optional OffsetValue As Long = 0) As Object
    Dim json As Object, http As Object
    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .Send
        'Debug.Print .Status, .responseText
        If .Status = 200 Then
            'Set responseObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
           ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Books").Cells(1, 3).Offset(OffsetValue) = .responseText
        Else
            Debug.Print .responseText, .Status
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Now, the output goes into `Cells(1, 3).Offset(OffsetValue)`, and since `OffsetValue` is incrementing by 1 each time, the output is moving down 1 row each time a value is written into the worksheet.